# What model is a suitable model for zero-constrained variables?

Tags: regression, distributions

After reading the answer in [How do I normalize a bimodal distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385513/how-do-i-normalize-a-bimodal-distribution), I began to think about the concept more broadly. With OLS on zero-constrained variables, the residuals signal bias, as the zero-conditional mean fails to hold (if I'm not mistaken).

### Question

Aside from demeaning, what is the conventional approach for zero-constrained variables, and what (if anything) changes if the zero-constrained variable is a response / explanatory variable?

Comment: What is a zero-constrained variable?